# File explorer/ File manager like android

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm starting a project in which i can view all image's/Documments/files all the phone storage data of the iphone device.

Like File Explorer app in which we can see all folder and data in the storage in the Iphone devices and i can do all operations like cut, copy  image's, file's etc to another folders in phone.

example :- like we have Es file explorer application in android. I need to create it for iphone.
Can copy image's to OTG device's. create , update , delete file's, etc
any links of tutorials or suggesting site for this project.

For Example for IOS : - IUSB Drive app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider).

Using this your app can access the documents and directories stored and managed by your other apps.

There are some Limitation that you can't do all features like ES File explorer does.

Some tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1060-ios-extensions-document-provider-tutorial

https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/managing-files-in-ios-dfcdfdc1f426

Comment: thanks and i need we can copy images by going to images folders